# Using System.ComponentModel in a .NET Core Class Library

Tags: c#, .net-core, class-library

I'm now playing with .NET Core Class Library projects and testing some code that I already have in a regular class library project targeting .NET Framework.

I installed the `System.ComponentModel` NuGet package to use annotations in an `enum`. Looks like it's not recognizing the annotation.

Here's what the enum looks like:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public enum UserRole
{
   [Description("Undefined")]
   Undefined = 0,
   [Description("Super User")]
   SuperUser = 1,
   [Description("Administrator")]
   Admin = 2,
   [Description("Regular User")]
   RegUser = 4
}
```

The error I'm seeing is:

> The type or namespace name 'DescriptionAttribute' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

The using `System.ComponentModel` reference at the top is grayed out and looks like it's not being used at all.

Two questions:

1. I suspect I'll run into many similar issues. What's the best way for me to figure out any differences between .NET Framework and .NET Core class library references?
2. What's the solution to being able to use annotations in a .NET Core Class Library?

P.S. The code is working perfectly in my class library project targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2. So I'm only transferring code that I know to be working into my new .NET Core Class Library project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DescriptionAttribute you need to use the System.ComponentModel.Primitives package (version 4.1 and above).

Here's a handy website that you can look up the packages / support for APIs:
https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=descriptionattribute